# Why is * not being greedy in preg_match by default?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

Using the string ABC123 as my subject, matching [A-Z]* does match "ABC" as intended, but trying to match [0-9]* returns an empty string. I'm under the assumption that preg_match is greedy by default, and those two very similar regular expressions behave really differently

Comment: Use `[0-9]+`, else `[0-9]*` matches an empty string before the first char that is not a digit.

Comment: it prefers to match 0 digits earlier in the string to 3 digits later in the string.